# OAuth 2.0 authentication silently failing in Google Blogger JavaScript API (v3)

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, blogger

Until recently I was using the **javascript Blogger API v3** to fetch posts from a blog to build an automated index, using the `gapi.client.blogger.posts.list()` method.

However, it suddenly stopped working. The response now simply includes an error object with the message `"We're sorry, but the requested resource could not be found."`, as if the blog I'm trying to fetch info does not exist at all. I'm pretty sure my blog ID did not change during my sleep.

So I started digging around, and I found that the OAuth authentication token returned says **I'm not actually logged in Google**. In the `status` object from the token, the `signed_in` property is true but the `google_logged_in` one is false. Yet the Google login page showed up correctly upon execution and I allowed it, and the token does not have an error property. Why does it says I'm not logged in?

I'm under the assumption that Google blocked my application from making new requests due repeated use (even thought I never reached a dent of the daily quota) and now since the OAuth 2 ID authentication does not work, the API tries to use only the web browser API key, which does not work either since it's a private blog and user permission is required. But I really don't know.

I could not find a similar situation on the internet. I tried deleting both my API and OAuth keys and making new ones, deleting the project from the Google Console Developers and creating a new one under a different account, removing the application from the "allowed apps" in my account and adding it again, not using the browser API key. No game.

I would appreciate any inputs in solving this issue. And before anyone suggests: the "conventional" way of creating an automated index using the blog's feed does not work in my case, since the blog is private and has no feed.

Bellow is the returned access token (redacted a bit):

```json
{
 _aa: "1"
 access_token: "[Redacted]"
 client_id: "[Redacted]"
 cookie_policy: undefined
 expires_at: "1460999668"
 expires_in: "3600"
 g_user_cookie_policy: undefined
 issued_at: "1460996068"
 response_type: "token"
 scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger.readonly"
 state: ""
 status: {
  google_logged_in: false
  method: "AUTO"
  signed_in: true
 }
 token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

And bellow an example code of my application:

```js
var apiKey   = "myWebBrowserApiKey";
var clientId = "myOAuth2ClientID";
var blogId   = "myBlogID";
var bloggerReadOnly = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger.readonly";

var fetchParam = {
    blogId:      blogId,
    fetchBodies: false,
    fetchImages: false,
    maxResults:  500,
    status:      "live",
    view:        "READER"
};

var authParamIm = {
    client_id: clientId,
    scope:     bloggerReadOnly,
    immediate: true
};

var authParam = {
    client_id: clientId,
    scope:     bloggerReadOnly,
    immediate: false
};

//Executed as soon the client:blogger.js loads
function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}

//Check if the user is already authenticated for immediate access
function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize( authParamIm, handleAuthResult );
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

    //If the user does already have authorization, proceed with the API call
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        makeApiCall();
    }

    //If he does not, shows the authorization button
    else {
        authorizeButton.css('visibility', 'visible');
        authorizeButton.click(handleAuthClick);
    }
}

//The authorization button calls this function, that shows a Google login page
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize( authParam, handleAuthResult );
    return false;
}

//Loads the Blogger API, version 3, and runs the fetchPosts() function with a callback
function makeApiCall(){
    gapi.client.load('blogger', 'v3', fetchPosts);
}

function fetchPosts(){

    //Creates a request to get a list of posts from the blog, using the fetch parameters
    var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list(fetchParam);

    //Execute the request and treats the response with a callback function
    request.execute(function(response){
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```